# How can I tell what external hard drives a domain user has plugged in?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, hard-drive

Is there any way to track what hard drives currently are, or have been plugged in to a domain computer? All of the workstations are windows xp and the domain controllers are server 2003. The closest i can find is the disk management snap in.

Answer (score 3):

You can interrogate the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class for information.

This will show you any disk drive attached to your computer at the present moment in time - I'm not even sure if you can get historical information. This includes hard disks, memory card readers, USB memory sticks and external hard disks.